# value of 0 log0 in entropy formula

Tags: information-theory

Why is the value of $p_i\log(p_i)$ in entropy formula considered $0$ when $p_i =0$? I get that it is the limiting value, but does that mean $p$ is never equals to zero, but only tends to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible answers:

- If a symbol has probability zero, then it does not influence the calculation and there is no need to include it, so you never actually calculate $0\log(0)$.
- If you insist in including symbols with zero probability, then $0\log(0)=0$ by convention.

Comment: it doesn't have to be *"by convention"*.  the limit $$ \lim_{p \to 0} p \log(p) = 0 $$

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I would agree only if you write the limit with $p \rightarrow 0^+$. But the limit itself (the "two-sided limit") does not exist, as far as I understand these things.

Comment: yeah you're right.  too late to change it.  oops.

Answer (score 2):

I am not adding a lot to MBaz, mostly graphical hints. It can be interesting to look at the elementary function behind Shannon entropy: $H: p\mapsto -p \log p -(1-p) \log (1-p)$, displayed below:

[image: Shannon Entropy for bernoulli probability]

While it seems not defined at $p=0$ or $p=1$, the function $H$  is very symmetric and behaves quite well at $0$ and $1$ for a Bernoulli trial.  Here, we talk about a binary event ($X$ happens with probability $p=P(X)$. The converse event is "not $X$". While entropy is often described as a measure of information, it can be seen as a measure of uncertainty. If $X$ is always equal to 1, it is certain. If $X$ never occurs, its converse is certain as well. In both cases, we have not surprise: the uncertainty is zero, and the "definitions" $-p \log p = 0$ for $p=0$ or  $-(1-p) \log (1-p) =0$ for $p=1$ make sense.

More details can be found in [Entropy is a measure of uncertainty](https://towardsdatascience.com/entropy-is-a-measure-of-uncertainty-e2c000301c2c).